# Identify and convert timezone in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-3.x, python-dateutil

In my file I have columns of date in the ISO 8061 format with timezone information, here is the sample input

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00-05:00
2009-01-29T07:00:00-05:00
2009-01-29T13:00:00-05:00
2009-01-29T18:55:00-05:00
2010-01-22T12:00:00-05:00
2010-07-20T00:25:00-04:00
2010-08-14T00:30:00-04:00
2011-06-19T08:25:00.41683-04:00
```

so the format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS[f]-AB:CD

I want to know how I can format the given data to format required by  RFC 2445 iCalendar specification [DTSTART], which are example :

```
19970714T133000                    ;Local time
19970714T173000Z                   ;UTC time
TZID=US-Eastern:19970714T133000    ;Local time and time
```

I currently have following code for just parsing

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import dateutil
>>> import datetime
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2009-01-29T07:00:00-05:00')
datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 29, 7, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

I want to know how to identify time zone ['-04:00','-05:00'] and how to convert them into UTC.

Thank you.

Comment: I am a little confused.dateutil has already parsed timezone info for you. tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000). an hour has 3600s. -5:00 is -18000s

Comment: @Leonardo.Z so if I just subtract 5 hours from the original datetime, I would get UTC datetime ?

Comment: No, you should not do the subtract manually.  `dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2009-01-29T07:00:00-05:00')`, datatime object has a method to do the timezone conversion: `dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)`

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Thanks Leo :) Hope you have a relaxing day :)

Comment: Leonardo is right.  Besides, you would *add* 5 hours to get back to UTC.  The offset means that the time is 5 hours *behind* UTC.  Also recognize that just because you have -5 or -4 doesn't mean you can know that this is US Eastern Time.

Comment: Given that `-05:00` maps to several different timezones, and that set of timezones can differ based on the time of year (due to daylight savings time), this is not likely to give you great results, but it depends on how picky you are... `-05:00` could be US/Eastern, but it is also US/Central during part of the year (during which US/Eastern is `-04:00`)... But maybe you should be looking at the central or south American zones, or ...... ?

Comment: @twalberg There is also one hour per year where US Eastern and Central are *both* at -5.  [See here for details](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20131103T01&p1=64&p2=179).

Comment: @MattJohnson Yep... Probably also one hour where neither are at -5... In general time zone handling is tricky...

Comment: @twalberg - Yes.  During the spring-forward transition, they are two hours apart.  One is -4 and the other is -6.  [Details here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130310T01&p1=64&p2=179)